# How to only do a SMS verification for email/password account in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have got the `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number, appVerifier)` to work nicely, but realized something that I didn't before. As soon as you put in the sms verification code it creates a whole other user under the phone auth, which makes since.

What I want to do however is just allow my current email/password users to add a phone number and then before they sign in have to go through a process of getting a verification sms code and put it in and only then through the success block log that user in.

My current solution is to add the phone number to the email/password account. Go through the phone auth process and if successful log out the phone auth account and then log the email/password account in with the same phone number. This sounds like a bad idea in the long run however, so is there a sms verification without authentication in firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to link your email/password user with a phone number credential using linkWithPhoneNumber method of User. 
Check out the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth
Linking to a phone number credential requires the user to verify their phone number with SMS code.

Comment: I actually did the `updatePhoneNumber` and then after that did the `signInWithPhoneNumber` and it seemed to link them together without making another `phone number` account. So in providers it shows a phone icon and email icon instead of two separate accounts with one phone and one email. Not sure why it works but it does lol

Answer (score 1):

That case does sound like a bad idea.

Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't yet provide SMS verifications without Phone Auth. You'll have to look for a different way to do that.

Comment: I have it working with the solution I proposed but that means creating an account for both phone and email each time. I don't want to have to use twilio.